# iOS/Swift: How to manage image downloading from Firebase in a feed

Tags: ios, swift, image, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to implement a feed for images using Firebase Storage, think of it like the Instagram photo feed. 
My Problem:

- I don't know how many images there are in my Firebase reference folder
- I want only the images to be shown that have been taken, let's say in the last week

I tried downloading the images from the reference like this:

```
let storageRef = storage.reference()


    for i in 0...10 {

        let imageRef = storageRef.child("images/" + String(i) + ".jpg")

        imageRef.dataWithMaxSize((10 * 1024 *  1024), completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error)
            } else {
                let image: UIImage! = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.downloadedPhotos.append(image) //downloadedPhotos is an array of UIImages

                self.configureFeed() //takes care of some UI

            }
        })
    }
```

Here I run into the obvious problem: I've only downloaded 10 images, called "1","2",..., "10"

- What kind of way to name the images when users upload them would you suggest?
- How could I keep track of how many images there are?
- How could I delete those images from the reference that are older than a week?
- Should I use Image Cashing Libraries like Kingfisher or would you go with the above style?

Thank you guys really much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's handle these one at a time:

- What kind of way to name the images when users upload them would you 
  suggest?

I'd take a look at the many other questions like this: [Retrieving image from Firebase Storage using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398282/retrieving-image-from-firebase-storage-using-swift)

- How could I keep track of how many images there are?

See above.

- How could I delete those images from the reference that are older than a 
  week?

You can use [Object Lifecycle Management](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle#configuration) to delete images after a certain time. Deleting them from the database would be harder--maybe an integration with [Google Cloud Functions GCS notifications](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage) could sync this.

- Should I use Image Cashing Libraries like Kingfisher or would
  you go with the above style?

I totally recommend using an image loader like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) or [PINRemoteImage](https://github.com/pinterest/PINRemoteImage) after pulling the download image from the realtime database.

Comment: Thanks for your help, looking forward to dive into these technics.

Comment: Really happy it worked out indeed. The combination of Storage and using a downloadURL stored in the realtime database made it all work out. Thank you really much for the provided links.