# Kingfisher with Firebase storage slow to display images - swift 3

Tags: firebase, swift3, uiimage, firebase-storage, kingfisher

Im saving images from a picker up to firebase. Then I'm bringing them back down to my Tableview, but they update really slowly from kingfisher. even from the cache. If I reload the app offline, they still take time to appear

Saving up to Firebase Storage

```
    func Save(image:UIImage, folderName:String, storeRefString:String,         dbRefString:String) {
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "Main")
        let database = FIRDatabase.database()
        let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
        let mainScreenItem = MainItem(name: folderName, image: "")
        let mainItemRef = ref.child(folderName.lowercased())
        let storageRef = storage.reference().child(storeRefString)
        mainItemRef.setValue(mainScreenItem.toAnyObject())

        let fileData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! as NSData

        storageRef.put(fileData as Data).observe(.success) { (snapshot) in
            let downloadURL = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
            let dbRef = database.reference().child(dbRefString)
            dbRef.setValue(downloadURL)

        }
    }
```

ViewDidLoad()

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    maxHeaderHeight = 100
    minHeaderHeight = 50
    ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "name").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        var newItems: [MainItem] = []
        for item in snapshot.children {
            let groceryItem = MainItem(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            newItems.append(groceryItem)
        }
        self.items = newItems
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    })
}
```

CellForRowAtIndexPath

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainTableViewCell") as! MainTableViewCell
    let item = items[indexPath.row]
    let url = URL(string: item.image)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        () -> Void in
        cell.photoImage?.kf.setImage(with: url)
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reduced the size of the images. this seemed to fix the issue