# Swift 4: Fetch images from Firebase storage and display them in the table View

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4, firebase-storage

I have not found any good examples/code for fetching an image from firebase storage/database and displaying it in cells in a basic table view. I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398282/retrieving-image-from-firebase-storage-using-swift) as but found nothing that worked. Can someone give a full example?

Bellow is code I have tried to make it work:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

        //TableView datasource methods

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
            self.downloadImages(cell: cell, folderPath: "\(Storage.storage().reference().child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("post\(takePicViewController().finalPost + PhotoArray.sharedInstance.numberPost)").child(ImageUploadManager().imageName))", success: { (img) in
                print(img)
            }) { (error) in
                print(error)
            }

//            cell.imageView?.image = PhotoArray.sharedInstance.photosArray[indexPath.row] as? UIImage
            return cell
        }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            let numberOfRowsInSection = PhotoArray.sharedInstance.photosArray
            return numberOfRowsInSection.count 
        }

    func downloadImages(cell: UITableViewCell, folderPath:String,success:@escaping (_ image:UIImage)->(),failure:@escaping (_ error:Error)->()){
        for i in 0 ..< 194{
            // Create a reference with an initial file path and name
            let reference = Storage.storage().reference().child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("post\(takePicViewController().finalPost + PhotoArray.sharedInstance.numberPost)").child(ImageUploadManager().imageName)
            reference.getData(maxSize: (1 * 1024 * 1024)) { (data, error) in
                if let _error = error{
                    print(_error)
                    failure(_error)
                } else {
                    if let _data  = data {
                        let myImage:UIImage! = UIImage(data: _data)
                        success(myImage)
                    }
                }
//                let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
                cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }

        }
    }

}
```

I have also tried the bellow code:

At the beggining of the VC I do the following:

```
    // Firebase services
var database: Database!
var storage: Storage!

// Initialize Database, Auth, Storage
override func viewDidLoad() {
    database = Database.database()
    storage = Storage.storage()
}
```

Then I call the function inside the ***tableView_cellforRowAt indexPath*** function as seen bellow. And I return cell

```
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
       loadArrayOfImages(cell: cell)

       return cell
```

The function I called looks like this:

```
    func loadArrayOfImages(cell: UITableViewCell) {

    let dbRef = database.reference().child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("post\(takePicViewController().finalPost + PhotoArray.sharedInstance.numberPost)").child(ImageUploadManager().imageName)
    dbRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Get download URL from snapshot
        let downloadURL = snapshot.value as! String
        // Create a storage reference from the URL
        let storageRef = self.storage.reference(forURL: downloadURL)
        // Download the data, assuming a max size of 1MB (you can change this as necessary)
        storageRef.getData(maxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
            // Create a UIImage, add it to the array
            let pic = UIImage(data: data!)
            self.picArray.append(pic!)
            cell.imageView?.image = pic
        }
    })

   }
}
```

I do not seem to get any errors and the app does not crash however when I press a button to take me to the TV it is just blanc.

Comment: You don't need to download the image you can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) and pass the imageUrl directly.

Comment: Why web image? this is ios app and we are usinng images created by user

Comment: If you checked the above library this is for iOS application. It does asynchronously download the image for a specific `UIImageView`. Don't misunderstand by its name. :)

Comment: @AlexanderTheGreat **Use this for load image** https://stackoverflow.com/a/51746300/10150796

Answer (score 0):

It could be something as simple as reloading your tableView. Remember that your data request to the Firebase servers will not return instantaneously as it is a network call, and as such it could be that your table has 'set' itself before the data has come back. To remedy this, you should use `tableView.reloadData()`. You could put this at the end of your `loadArrayOfImages()` function like so:

```
...
cell.imageView?.image = pic
tableView.reloadData()
```