# Uploading and using images on Firebase/Storage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I just started to use `Firebase/Storage` and I have the following question.

First here is the situation:

I have an image called myImage.gif that I uploaded to `Firebase/Storage`. It all works fine.
I get a download URL for recovering the file at a later time.

For reference this is how I get the downloadURL:

```
......
imageRef.downloadURL(completion: {
    (url: URL?, error: Error?) in
    if (error == nil) {
        if let downloadUrl = url {
            // Get the download URL.
            let downloadURL = downloadUrl.absoluteString
            print("This is the downloadURL: \(downloadURL)")
        }
    } else {
        print("Error:\n\(error!)")
    }
});
```

The URL for downloading looks like this:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/.../CollectionName%2myImage.gif?alt=media&token=abc12d34-2ex1-4xyz-5re4-c6d8ggqde765
```

And if I use it I can indeed download the file.

Now here is the question:

Being able to download the file is all right, but this is not exactly what I am interested in.
I want a URL that I can use in a web page to bring the image to the view of the user, in other words to use like this:

```
<img src="theURL" alt="My wonderful image!">
```

How can I get such a URL? (instead of one for downloading)

Comment: This is precisely how the download URL is normally used.  Are you saying it doesn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398282/retrieving-image-from-firebase-storage-using-swift

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving image from Firebase Storage using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398282/retrieving-image-from-firebase-storage-using-swift)

Comment: Sorry. Yes it works. Since I did not see the image, but a download dialog when I clicked the link I misunderstood, but when used with the proper syntax in javascript, it works.