# How to download or retrieve image from firebase storage in SwiftUI or Swift 5

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

What do I have to write in else body to retrieve image from firebase storage and display it in UI?

```
public func downloadFile(url: String){

    var img: Image?

    let storage = Storage.storage()
    let storageRef = storage.reference()
    let imageRef = storageRef.child("Wallpapers/Cars/Wallpaper1.jpg")
    imageRef.downloadURL { (url, err) in
        if let err = err{
            print("Error! Unable to download")
        }
        else{

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving image from Firebase Storage using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398282/retrieving-image-from-firebase-storage-using-swift)

Comment: No it does not because that is the old version of swift.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For swift 5, you can use this :

```
let Ref = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: yourUrl)
Ref.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
    if error != nil {
        print("Error: Image could not download!")
    } else {
        yourImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
    }
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Could you please tell more precisely how do I connect yourImageView with Image() in Hstack

Comment: I don't know. This is for swift 5.

Comment: ref.putData(image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)!, metadata: metadata)

Answer (score 1):

This could be a way:

```
// Create a reference to the file you want to download
let storageRef = FirebaseStorage.StorageReference()
let imgsRef    = storageRef.child(imgURL)

// Fetch the download URL
imgsRef.downloadURL { url, error in
    if error != nil {
        // Handle error
    } else {
        // Get the image
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
             guard let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data) else { return }
            RunLoop.main.perform {
                 self.initialImage = image
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```