# Cannot download image from Cloud Firestore database

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

This is the tableviewController which supposed to show image in each row but it does not. [image] When I run the application on simulator it starts and displays the table view with titles and subtitles but images. I also attach the screenshots of simulator with some prints and of the structure of the database.[image]

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import Combine

class ListOfVideoLessonsTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    
    let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer()
    
    private var viewModel = VideosViewModel()
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    var player = AVPlayer()
    var playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    
    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 
        self.viewModel.fetchData()
        
        self.title = "Video Lessons"
        
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        
        cancellable = viewModel.$videos.sink { _ in
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                
                self.table.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("videos count = ", viewModel.videos.count)
        return viewModel.videos.count
}
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let video = viewModel.videos[indexPath.row]
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = video.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = video.lessonName
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        let image = UIImage(named: video.imageName)
        cell.imageView?.image = image
        let backgroundView = UIView()
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "VideoLessonsCellHighlighted")
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 14)
        cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)
        
        return cell
}
    

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
}
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        playVideo(at: indexPath)
}
    
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "VideoLessonsCellHighlighted")
            cell.textLabel?.highlightedTextColor = UIColor(named: "textHighlighted")
            cell.detailTextLabel?.highlightedTextColor = UIColor(named: "textHighlighted")
    }
}

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didUnhighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = nil
            
    }
}
    
        func playVideo(at indexPath: IndexPath){
            let selectedVideo = viewModel.videos[indexPath.row]
            let videoURL = URL(string: selectedVideo.fileURL)
            player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
            playerViewController.player = player
            
            
          self.present(playerViewController, animated: true, completion: {
                self.playerViewController.player?.play()
        })
           
    }
}
```

This is the viewModel which I believe should download images and pass to the tableview cells.

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore


class VideosViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var videos = [Video]()
private var db = Firestore.firestore()

func fetchData() {
    db.collection("videos").addSnapshotListener { [self] (querySnapshot, error) in
    guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
    print("No Documents")
    return
}

self.videos = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Video in
    let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                
    let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
    let imageName = data["imageName"] as? String ?? ""
    let lessonName  = data["lessonName"] as? String ?? ""
    let fileURL  = data["fileURL"] as? String ?? ""
              
    print(data)


    return Video(name: name , imageName: imageName , lessonName: lessonName, fileURL: fileURL )
                
              
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this the struct of the video

```
import Foundation

struct Video {
    var name: String
    var imageName: String
    var lessonName: String
    var fileURL: String
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download or retrieve image from firebase storage in SwiftUI or Swift 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61277647/how-to-download-or-retrieve-image-from-firebase-storage-in-swiftui-or-swift-5)

Answer (score 1):

Does an image with that '**video.imageName**' exist within the app?

```
let image = UIImage(named: video.imageName)
cell.imageView?.image = image
```

you should be download from firebase storage.

use to

```
guard let url = URL(string: video.imageName) else {return}
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL, completionHandler: (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)
```

Answer (score 1):

the first answer is one option however you will encounter the frozen screen while scrolling the UITableView.
if you want to void that. Then you can use SDWebImage SDK

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImage

class ListOfVideoLessonsTableViewController {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let video = viewModel.videos[indexPath.row]
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = video.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = video.lessonName
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        let image = UIImage(named: video.imageName)
        cell.imageView?.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.gray
        cell.imageView ?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: stringWithoutWhitespace), placeholderImage: UIImage())      
        let backgroundView = UIView()
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "VideoLessonsCellHighlighted")
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 14)
        cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)
        
        return cell
    }
}
```